# Is there still a way to clear the screen in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I just want to know because it is not working with the other commands, for instance, the ANSI way to clear and the os module way or the function. Nothing is working. Does this still exist?

Comment: "Nothing is working" is useless. Using os comamnd like `cls` or `clear` (depending on OS) is not python related. i.e. it's from the OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
os.system('clear')  # linux/osx
os.system('cls')  # windows
```

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought